# Get the specific value of default nonatomic parameter

Tags: r, default-value, function-parameter

I need to use the function `capwords()` from SGP in the way to get approach to use the value of default parameter `special.words` extended with my additional words. I.e. I need to do somthing like:

```
capwords("What do you think about chat GPT version IV", c(formals(capwords)$special.words,"GPT"))
```

But instead

> "What Do You Think About Chat GPT Version IV"

I've got "Iv" instead of "IV"

> "What Do You Think About Chat GPT Version Iv"

But "IV" is the part of `special.words` list.

And this because of `class(formals(capwords)$special.words)` is `"call"`.

**But how to get the specific value of `special.words` as the list but not the call?**

I can do that by using `eval()`:

```
> capwords("What do you think about chat GPT version IV", c(eval(formals(capwords)$special.words),"GPT"))
```

> [1] "What Do You Think About Chat GPT Version IV"

But I don't want.

This is not only about capwords() function but in general there are the same behaviour for any function with default parameter.

**So, are there other ways to do so except eval()?**

Comment: What's the initialism SGP?

Comment: @Hugh, SGP is the Student Growth Percentiles package. But it doesn't matter at all what the abbreviation is because the point is how to get the specific value of the function parameter with default value instead the data classified as "call".